# Creating get state code function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am really new to creating functions, and cant seem to find anything similar to this posted online. I am not sure why that when I run this, I am returning blanks? I'm calling it by using a Select dbo.UDF_StateCode([State]) FROM... statement.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[UDF_StateCode] (@State NVARCHAR)
RETURNS NVARCHAR
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @StateCode NVARCHAR
SET @StateCode =
CASE 
WHEN @State = 'ALASKA' THEN 'AK'
WHEN @State = 'ALABAMA' THEN 'AL'
WHEN @State = 'ARKANSAS' THEN 'AR'
WHEN @State = 'AMERICAN SAMOA' THEN 'AS'
WHEN @State = 'ARIZONA' THEN 'AZ'
WHEN @State = 'CALIFORNIA' THEN 'CA'
WHEN @State = 'COLORADO' THEN 'CO'
WHEN @State = 'CONNECTICUT' THEN 'CT'
WHEN @State = 'DISTRICT OF COLUMBIA' THEN 'DC'
WHEN @State = 'DELAWARE'THEN 'DE' 
WHEN @State = 'FLORIDA' THEN 'FL'
WHEN @State = 'FEDERATED STATES OF MICRONESIA' THEN 'FM'
WHEN @State = 'GEORGIA' THEN 'GA'
WHEN @State = 'GUAM' THEN 'GU'
WHEN @State = 'HAWAII' THEN 'HI' 
WHEN @State = 'IOWA' THEN 'IA'
WHEN @State = 'IDAHO' THEN 'ID'
WHEN @State = 'ILLINOIS' THEN 'IL'
WHEN @State = 'INDIANA' THEN 'IN'
WHEN @State = 'KANSAS' THEN 'KS' 
WHEN @State = 'KENTUCKY' THEN 'KY'
WHEN @State = 'LOUISIANA' THEN 'LA'
WHEN @State = 'MASSACHUSETTS' THEN 'MA'
WHEN @State = 'MARYLAND' THEN 'MD' 
WHEN @State = 'MAINE' THEN 'ME'
WHEN @State = 'MARSHALL ISLANDS' THEN 'MH' 
WHEN @State = 'MICHIGAN' THEN 'MI'
WHEN @State = 'MINNESOTA' THEN 'MN'
WHEN @State = 'MISSOURI' THEN 'MO'
WHEN @State = 'NORTHERN MARIANA ISLANDS' THEN 'MP'
WHEN @State = 'MISSISSIPPI' THEN 'MS'
WHEN @State = 'MONTANA' THEN 'MT'
WHEN @State = 'NORTH CAROLINA' THEN 'NC'
WHEN @State = 'NORTH DAKOTA' THEN 'ND'
WHEN @State = 'NEBRASKA' THEN 'NE'
WHEN @State = 'NEW HAMPSHIRE' THEN 'NH' 
WHEN @State = 'NEW JERSEY' THEN 'NJ' 
WHEN @State = 'NEW MEXICO' THEN 'NM'
WHEN @State = 'NEVADA' THEN 'NV'
WHEN @State = 'NEW YORK' THEN 'NY'
WHEN @State = 'OHIO' THEN 'OH'
WHEN @State = 'OKLAHOMA' THEN 'OK'
WHEN @State = 'OREGON' THEN 'OR'
WHEN @State = 'PENNSYLVANIA' THEN 'PA'
WHEN @State = 'PUERTO RICO'THEN 'PR' 
WHEN @State = 'RHODE ISLAND' THEN 'RI'
WHEN @State = 'SOUTH CAROLINA' THEN 'SC'
WHEN @State = 'SOUTH DAKOTA' THEN 'SD'
WHEN @State = 'TENNESSEE' THEN 'TN'
WHEN @State = 'TEXAS' THEN 'TX'
WHEN @State = 'UTAH' THEN 'UT'
WHEN @State = 'VIRGINIA ' THEN 'VA'
WHEN @State = 'VIRGIN ISLANDS' THEN 'VI' 
WHEN @State = 'VERMONT' THEN 'VT'
WHEN @State = 'WASHINGTON' THEN 'WA'
WHEN @State = 'WISCONSIN' THEN 'WI'
WHEN @State = 'WEST VIRGINIA' THEN 'WV'
WHEN @State = 'WYOMING' THEN 'WY'
ELSE ''
END
RETURN @StateCode
END;
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: A much better approach than this unwieldy function you should create a States table with both values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to declare a length for `nvarchar()`. It is defaulting to a length of 1.

Try this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[UDF_StateCode] (@State NVARCHAR(64)) 
RETURNS NVARCHAR(2)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @StateCode NVARCHAR(2) ...
```

[Bad habits to kick : declaring `varchar` without (length) - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - you should always provide a length for all `varchar` or `nvarchar` variables/parameters.

---

You could simplify your return to `nchar(2)` instead of a variable length output.

You could also improve the performance by writing this function as an in-line table valued function instead of a scalar function.

Normally this sort of thing would be a table instead of a function, and you would join to the table as needed. But for learning how to write functions, I guess it is a reasonable example.

---

Some good articles about the performance of functions:

- [When is a SQL function not a function? "If it’s not inline, it’s rubbish." - Rob Farley](http://blogs.lobsterpot.com.au/2011/11/08/when-is-a-sql-function-not-a-function/)
- [Inline Scalar Functions - Itzik Ben-Gan](http://sqlmag.com/sql-server/inline-scalar-functions)
- [Scalar functions, inlining, and performance: An entertaining title for a boring post - Adam Machanic](http://dataeducation.com/scalar-functions-inlining-and-performance-an-entertaining-title-for-a-boring-post/)
- [TSQL User-Defined Functions: Ten Questions You Were Too Shy To Ask - Robert Sheldon](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/sql-training/tsql-user-defined-functions-ten-questions-you-were-too-shy-to-ask/)

Comment: Thank you for the response! That worked. Why do we have define both the RETURNS and DECLARE as NCHAR(2)? I will definitely study up on some of those resources you provided.

Comment: @OhioMike1987 The two aren't necessarily related to each other, it is just how you have written it. Here is an example of how it can be written that skips your `declare`: http://rextester.com/ZFOQA63621 -- and here is an inline table valued function version of your function: http://rextester.com/KSUT98235

Comment: This certainly fixes the issue but I would suggest that using a function for this is the wrong tool for the job. This should be in a table that the OP can join to and forget about using a function with hard coded values instead of a lookup table.

Comment: @SeanLange I said that in my answer. "Normally this sort of thing would be a table instead of a function, and you would join to the table as needed. But for learning how to write functions, I guess it is a reasonable example. " -- Still a good point though.

Comment: Oops I missed that sentence. :) And yes learning the right way to build a function this is a reasonable example.